# Firebase deploy error _d.map is not a function (converterConfig)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, node-modules, google-workspace

I have 2 environments of the same project (react + firebase) in firebase hosting, one for development and one for production. I can correctly send files to firebase in the dev environment, but in the production environment it gives the following error below from

command used

```
npm run build && firebase deploy
```

Firebase-debug.log

```
[debug] [2023-03-18T01:56:48.988Z] TypeError: _d.map is not a function
    at convertConfig (.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/hosting/convertConfig.js:165:91)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async .nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/hosting/release.js:21:21
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async release (.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/hosting/release.js:14:5)
at async chain (.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:35:9)
at async deploy (.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:81:5)
```

> [error]  [error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

I went to the file indicated by the error and indeed there is _d.map. It looks like firebase hosting is unable to send the headers for the deploy request.

```
config.headers = (_d = deploy.config.headers) === null || _d === void 0 ? void 0 : _d.map((header) => {
    const headers = {};
    for (const { key, value } of header.headers || []) {
        headers[key] = value;
    }
    return Object.assign(Object.assign({}, extractPattern("header", header)), { headers });
});
```

Node: v14.18.1

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^18.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^2.1.0",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^2.7.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^2.7.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-bootstrap4": "^2.7.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "cpf-cnpj-validator": "^1.0.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "custom-error": "^0.2.1",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draft-js-export-html": "^1.4.1",
    "draft-js-import-html": "^1.4.1",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "firebase": "^8.4.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "js-base64": "^2.6.4",
    "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "qrcode.react": "^0.9.3",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.7.0",
    "react-currency-input": "^1.3.4",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.16.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-file-viewer": "^1.2.1",
    "react-filter-search": "^1.0.11",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-intl-currency-input": "^0.2.6",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.2.0",
    "react-notification-alert": "0.0.12",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.18",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^3.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "valid-url": "^1.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build --max-old-space-size=8192",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy:dev": "npm run build && firebase deploy --only hosting:ingresso-gospel-dev",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy",
    "build:deploy": "npm run build && node node_modules/react-build-cache && firebase deploy"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-build-cache": "^1.1.4",
    "webpack": "4.44.2"
  }
}
```

firebase.json

```
    {
    "database": {
      "rules": "database.rules.json"
    },
    "hosting": [
      {
         "headers": {
           "source": "/service-worker.js",
           "headers": [
             {
               "key": "Cache-Control",
               "value": "no-cache"
             }
           ]
        },
        "target": "project",
        "public": "build",
        "rewrites": [
          {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
          }
        ],
        "ignore": [
          "firebase.json",
          "**/.*",
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      },
      {
        "target": "project-dev",
        "public": "build",
        "rewrites": [
          {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
          }
        ],
        "ignore": [
          "firebase.json",
          "**/.*",
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was remove headers from firebase.json and now I can sendo the files to prod environment.

Remove it

```
"headers": {
       "source": "/service-worker.js",
       "headers": [
         {
           "key": "Cache-Control",
           "value": "no-cache"
         }
       ]
    },
```